# Changing default field validator in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have custom `clean_*` form method, which does verify uploaded image type and file extension.

```
class TableModelForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_image(self):
        img_err = 'Unsupport image type. Please upload png, jpg or gif.'
        img_formats = ['png', 'jpeg', 'gif']
        img = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        if not img:
            return img
        img_fmt = img.image.format.lower()
        img_ext = splitext(img.name)[1][1:].lower()
        if any([x not in img_formats for x in [img_fmt, img_ext]]):
            raise ValidationError(ugettext_lazy(img_err), code='invalid_image')
        return img
```

It works well until the image of the appropriate format but without a file extension is attempted to upload, in which case `default_validator` kicks in and I see the default `FileExtensionValidator` error message:

```
File extension '' is not allowed. Allowed extensions are: 'bmp, bufr, cur, pcx, dcx, dds, ps, eps, fit, fits, fli, flc, fpx, ftc, ftu, gbr, gif, grib, h5, hdf, png, jp2, j2k, jpc, jpf, jpx, j2c, icns, ico, im, iim, tif, tiff, jfif, jpe, jpg, jpeg, mic, mpg, mpeg, mpo, msp, palm, pcd, pdf, pxr, pbm, pgm, ppm, psd, bw, rgb, rgba, sgi, ras, tga, webp, wmf, emf, xbm, xpm'.
```

Is there a way to replace the `default_validator` of the `ModelForm` field without re-declaring the field?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? You may find [ticket #28242](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28242), which was fixed in Django 1.11.2 relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `(1, 11, 4, 'final', 0)`, but not sure how the referenced ticked  could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting the field's `validators` to an empty list in the form's `__init__` method.

```
class TableModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].validators = []
```

Another option might be to subclass `ImageField` and change `default_validators`, then use your custom field in the model form.

I'm not really familiar with the internals of the file field and image field, so I'm not certain whether either approach will work.